# change wordpress plugin source code; no change on the site

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

i created a wp plugin, now, whenever i change it through

a) editor,
b) manually in Sublime Text2 and then delete from wp, and re-upload the changed version

and go to page with shortcode that's supposed to trigger plugin, i see no changes. i now have just few words and no html tags whatsoever in php page its supposed to include, it still displays the old html table that was there

here's the code i use to activate the plugin when i 'install' it in WP

```
    register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'act');

function act(){
  add_option('Activated_Plugin','Plugin-Slug');
  /* activation code here */
}


function getxml( $atts ){
 include 'getxml.php';
}
add_shortcode( 'boixml', 'getxml' );
```

Comment: do you mean it worked fine on first run, but after update it doesn't change. Or did it not run at all, from the start, and update doesn't have effect either.

Answer (score 0):

Did you install  `W3 Total Cache` or `WP Super Cache` plugins?

Try that link may it give you the key to solve that problem

http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Optimization/Caching